# How can I use covariant return types with smart pointers?

Tags: c++, covariance, smart-pointers

I have code like this:

```
class RetInterface {...}

class Ret1: public RetInterface {...}

class AInterface
{
  public:
     virtual boost::shared_ptr<RetInterface> get_r() const = 0;
     ...
};

class A1: public AInterface
{
  public:
     boost::shared_ptr<Ret1> get_r() const {...}
     ...
};
```

**This code does not compile.**

In visual studio it raises

> C2555: overriding virtual function return type differs and is not
>   covariant

If I do not use `boost::shared_ptr` but return raw pointers, the code compiles (I understand this is due to [covariant return types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_covariance#C.2B.2B) in C++). I can see the problem is because `boost::shared_ptr` of `Ret1` is not derived from `boost::shared_ptr` of `RetInterface`. But I want to return `boost::shared_ptr` of `Ret1` for use in other classes, else I must cast the returned value after the return.

1. Am I doing something wrong?
2. If not, why is the language like this - it should be extensible to handle conversion between smart pointers in this scenario? Is there a desirable workaround?

Comment: IF you don't use boost::shared_ptr, do you return pointers? Is it managed C++?

Comment: @Lev If I try returning raw pointers the code compiles, but then there is a memory management problem. No, I am not using managed C++.

Comment: What I do is: return raw pointers but document that the caller is responsible for wrapping the pointer in a smart pointer, e.g. `std::unique_ptr<Class>(obj.clone())`.

Comment: "_I can see the problem is because boost::shared_ptr of Ret1 is not derived from boost::shared_ptr of RetInterface_" No it isn't

Comment: Because it doesn't work with smart pointers here, it is recommended in this case to use gsl::owner<A1*> (see the [C-130](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c130-for-making-deep-copies-of-polymorphic-classes-prefer-a-virtual-clone-function-instead-of-public-copy-constructionassignment) recommendation from CppCoreguidelines)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Firstly, this is indeed how it works in C++: the return type of a virtual function in a derived class must be the same as in the base class. There is the special exception that a function that returns a reference/pointer to some class X can be overridden by a function that returns a reference/pointer to a class that derives from X, but as you note this doesn't allow for *smart* pointers (such as `shared_ptr`), just for plain pointers.

If your interface `RetInterface` is sufficiently comprehensive, then you won't need to know the actual returned type in the calling code. In general it doesn't make sense anyway: the reason `get_r` is a `virtual` function in the first place is because you will be calling it through a pointer or reference to the base class `AInterface`, in which case you can't know what type the derived class would return. If you are calling this with an actual `A1` reference, you can just create a separate `get_r1` function in `A1` that does what you need.

```
class A1: public AInterface
{
  public:
     boost::shared_ptr<RetInterface> get_r() const
     {
         return get_r1();
     }
     boost::shared_ptr<Ret1> get_r1() const {...}
     ...
};
```

Alternatively, you can use the visitor pattern or something like my [Dynamic Double Dispatch](http://www.ddj.com/dept/cpp/184429055) technique to pass a callback in to the returned object which can then invoke the callback with the correct type.

Comment: Will boost::shared_ptr<Ret1> automatically get converted to boost::shared_ptr<RetInterface>? Don't you need at least something like boost::static_pointer_cast?

Comment: Return the pointer to derived class makes sense with clone methods on classes implementing multiple interfaces.

Answer (score 6):

There is a neat solution posted in [this blog post](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/09/12/how-to-return-a-smart-pointer-and-use-covariance/) (from Raoul Borges)

An excerpt of the bit prior to adding support for mulitple inheritance and abstract methods is:

```
template <typename Derived, typename Base>
class clone_inherit<Derived, Base> : public Base
{
public:
   std::unique_ptr<Derived> clone() const
   {
      return std::unique_ptr<Derived>(static_cast<Derived *>(this->clone_impl()));
   }
 
private:
   virtual clone_inherit * clone_impl() const override
   {
      return new Derived(*this);
   }
};

class concrete: public clone_inherit<concrete, cloneable>
{
};

int main()
{
   std::unique_ptr<concrete> c = std::make_unique<concrete>();
   std::unique_ptr<concrete> cc = c->clone();
 
   cloneable * p = c.get();
   std::unique_ptr<clonable> pp = p->clone();
}
```

I would encourage reading the full article. Its simply written and well explained.

Comment: it's not b->clone(); but c->clone()

Comment: fixed as stated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What about this solution:

```c
template<typename Derived, typename Base>
class SharedCovariant : public shared_ptr<Base>
{
public:

typedef Base BaseOf;

SharedCovariant(shared_ptr<Base> & container) :
    shared_ptr<Base>(container)
{
}

shared_ptr<Derived> operator ->()
{
    return boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(*this);
}
};
```

e.g:

```c
struct A {};

struct B : A {};

struct Test
{
    shared_ptr<A> get() {return a_; }

    shared_ptr<A> a_;
};

typedef SharedCovariant<B,A> SharedBFromA;

struct TestDerived : Test
{
    SharedBFromA get() { return a_; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt :

```
template<class T>
class Child : public T
{
public:
    typedef T Parent;
};

template<typename _T>
class has_parent
{
private:
    typedef char                        One;
    typedef struct { char array[2]; }   Two;

    template<typename _C>
    static One test(typename _C::Parent *);
    template<typename _C>
    static Two test(...);

public:
    enum { value = (sizeof(test<_T>(nullptr)) == sizeof(One)) };
};

class A
{
public :
   virtual void print() = 0;
};

class B : public Child<A>
{
public:
   void print() override
   {
       printf("toto \n");
   }
};

template<class T, bool hasParent = has_parent<T>::value>
class ICovariantSharedPtr;

template<class T>
class ICovariantSharedPtr<T, true> : public ICovariantSharedPtr<typename T::Parent>
{
public:
   T * get() override = 0;
};

template<class T>
class ICovariantSharedPtr<T, false>
{
public:
    virtual T * get() = 0;
};

template<class T>
class CovariantSharedPtr : public ICovariantSharedPtr<T>
{
public:
    CovariantSharedPtr(){}

    CovariantSharedPtr(std::shared_ptr<T> a_ptr) : m_ptr(std::move(a_ptr)){}

    T * get() final
   {
        return m_ptr.get();
   }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> m_ptr;
};
```

And a little example :

```
class UseA
{
public:
    virtual ICovariantSharedPtr<A> & GetPtr() = 0;
};

class UseB : public UseA
{
public:
    CovariantSharedPtr<B> & GetPtr() final
    {
        return m_ptrB;
    }
private:
    CovariantSharedPtr<B> m_ptrB = std::make_shared<B>();
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    UseB b;
    UseA & a = b;
    a.GetPtr().get()->print();
}
```

Explanations :

This solution implies meta-progamming and to modify the classes used in covariant smart pointers.

The simple template struct `Child` is here to bind the type `Parent` and inheritance. Any class inheriting from `Child<T>` will inherit from `T` and define `T` as `Parent`. The classes used in covariant smart pointers needs this type to be defined.

The class `has_parent` is used to detect at compile time if a class defines the type `Parent` or not. This part is not mine, I used the same code as to detect if a method exists ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence))

As we want covariance with smart pointers, we want our smart pointers to mimic the existing class architecture. It's easier to explain how it works in the example.

When a `CovariantSharedPtr<B>` is defined, it inherits from `ICovariantSharedPtr<B>`, which is interpreted as `ICovariantSharedPtr<B, has_parent<B>::value>`. As `B` inherits from `Child<A>`, `has_parent<B>::value` is true, so `ICovariantSharedPtr<B>` is `ICovariantSharedPtr<B, true>` and inherits from `ICovariantSharedPtr<B::Parent>` which is `ICovariantSharedPtr<A>`. As `A` has no `Parent` defined, `has_parent<A>::value` is false, `ICovariantSharedPtr<A>` is `ICovariantSharedPtr<A, false>` and inherits from nothing.

The main point is as `B`inherits from `A`, we have `ICovariantSharedPtr<B>`inheriting from `ICovariantSharedPtr<A>`. So any method returning a pointer or a reference on `ICovariantSharedPtr<A>` can be overloaded by a method returning the same on `ICovariantSharedPtr<B>`.

Comment: What about adding some rationale and explanation for those with little time to decipher this? How does it compare to morabot's? Merci.

Answer (score -1):

[Mr Fooz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196733/smart-pointer-and-virtual#196744)  answered part 1 of your question. Part 2, it works this way because the compiler doesn't know if it will be calling AInterface::get_r or A1::get_r at compile time - it needs to know what return value it's going to get, so it insists on both methods returning the same type. This is part of the C++ specification.

For the workaround, if A1::get_r returns a pointer to RetInterface, the virtual methods in RetInterface will still work as expected, and the proper object will be deleted when the pointer is destroyed. There's no need for different return types.

Answer (score -2):

maybe you could use an out parameter to get around "covariance with returned boost shared_ptrs.

```
 void get_r_to(boost::shared_ptr<RetInterface>& ) ...
```

since I suspect a caller can drop in a more refined shared_ptr type as argument.