# How to accomplish covariant return types when returning a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost, return-value, covariance, shared-ptr

```
using namespace boost;

class A {};
class B : public A {};

class X {
  virtual shared_ptr<A> foo();
};

class Y : public X {
  virtual shared_ptr<B> foo();
};
```

The return types aren't covariant (nor are they, therefore, legal), but they would be if I was using raw pointers instead.  What's the commonly accepted idiom to work around this, if there is one?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196733/how-can-i-use-covariant-return-types-with-smart-pointers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that a solution is fundamentally impossible because covariance depends on pointer arithmetic which is incompatible with smart pointers.

When `Y::foo` returns `shared_ptr<B>` to a dynamic caller, it must be cast to `shared_ptr<A>` before use. In your case, a `B*` can (probably) simply be reinterpreted as an `A*`, but for multiple inheritance, you would need some magic to tell C++ about `static_cast<A*>(shared_ptr<B>::get())`.

Comment: Hmm, "fundamentally" covariance depends on conversion, and perhaps should work with implicitly convertible types. But that still wouldn't apply to `shared_ptr`.

Comment: "_But that still wouldn't apply to `shared_ptr`_" I don't get it: are `shared_ptr` not convertible?

Comment: @curiousguy Oh, oops it is. Still just a hypothetical though.

Answer (score 4):

Not directly, but you can fake it by making the actual virtual functions inaccessible from outside the class and wrapping the virtual function call into a non-virtual function. Downside is that you'll have to remember to implement this wrapper function on each derived class. But you could get around this by puting both the virtul function declaration and the wrapper into the macro.

```
using namespace boost; // for shared_ptr, make_shared and static_pointer_cast.

// "Fake" implementation of the clone() function.
#define CLONE(MyType) \
    shared_ptr<MyType> clone() \
    { \
        shared_ptr<Base> res = clone_impl(); \
        assert(dynamic_cast<MyType*>(res.get()) != 0); \
        return static_pointer_cast<MyType>(res); \
    }

class Base 
{
protected:
    // The actual implementation of the clone() function. 
    virtual shared_ptr<Base> clone_impl() { return make_shared<Base>(*this); }

public:
    // non-virtual shared_ptr<Base> clone();
    CLONE(Base)
};

class Derived : public Base
{
protected:
    virtual shared_ptr<Base> clone_impl() { return make_shared<Derived>(*this); }

public:
    // non-virtual shared_ptr<Derived> clone();
    CLONE(Derived)
};


int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Derived> p = make_shared<Derived>();
    shared_ptr<Derived> clone = p->clone();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It has been a while since this was answered. Now that c++11 is out, is there a better way?

Comment: @CoryBeutler. No, if you want to use shared_ptr. If you're willing to give up shared_ptr and are willing to use intrusive reference counting, then yes. In this case the functions would return raw pointers and to get automatic refcounting you just need to assign the result to a smart pointer (e.g. boost::intrusive_ptr).

Answer (score -1):

I just return a bare pointer and wrap it immediately in the shared pointer.

Comment: You almost never want to wrap someone else's bare pointer to shared_ptr.