# C++ override does not work with std::shared_pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, shared-ptr

Assuming I have the following example code:

```
class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

class A {
  virtual shared_ptr<Base> method();
};

class B : public A {
  virtual shared_ptr<Derived> method() override;
};
```

I get the following error (with VS 2013):

*error C2555: 'B::method': overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant from 'A::method'*

I believe the issue is that a `shared_ptr<Derived>` is not a specialization of / does not inherit `shared_ptr<Base>`.

**Is there a way to get shared pointers to work for inheritance?**

Comment: I would just have it return `shared_ptr<Base>` since that is what is expected by users of `class A` and not doing it on inherited `class B` violates LSP.

Comment: How are you planning on using this? Can you show us any actual code you're working on?

Comment: The idea is that you can avoid a cast, because if you return `shared_ptr<Base>` you would always need that

Comment: This is from our codebase which I can't show you, but it is not very different to the example above (except more complex)

Comment: Why would you need to cast? If you intend to use inheritance like this the actual class type should not make a difference for the user.

Comment: You cannot change the return type of a method when overriding, and `shared_ptr<Base>` is another type than `shared_ptr<Derived>`. It does not matter if you can cast one to the other.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687790/how-to-accomplish-covariant-return-types-when-returning-a-shared-ptr

Comment: @pschill I can change the return type, If it is covariant to the base return type

Comment: @kennytm thanks, didn't find that on my search, I guess it can be marked as duplicate then

Comment: @tobspr Oh okay, I was not aware of covariant return types.

Comment: @r_ahlskog: Just because a class has some virtual functions doesn't mean it is always used through a pointer to base class and that the actual type is irrelevant.

Comment: @MikeMB You are correct that type may be relevant. But then B should probably not inherit A or a different method should be used. As written the code in the question seems set up for confusing situations or an if-else tree of typechecks and casts. But without more context I cannot say what would be a more correct approach.