# Usefulness of covariant return types in C++ clone idiom?

Tags: c++, idioms

The usual clone idiom makes use of covariant return types:

```
struct Base {
    virtual Base* clone();
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    Derived* clone();
};
```

I've read things to the effect that covariant return types were a later addition to C++, and older compilers may not support them.  In this case the `Derived` class must declare its `clone` member function to return a `Base*`.  Since, presumably, I'm only accessing `Derived` objects through `Base` pointers and/or references when using this idiom, what is the real use/benefit to declaring the return type `Derived*`?

Also, a related question:

I would prefer to use smart pointers to express transfer-of-ownership semantics for the `clone` signature.  This is not possible when using covariant return types, as `auto_ptr<Derived>` is not covariant with `auto_ptr<Base>`.  (Please note that I'm not looking for a lecture on the use of smart pointers -- `auto_ptr` is just used as an example here).  So in this case, is there any reason not to have `Derived` return `auto_ptr<Base>`?  Is there a better way to express the transfer-of-ownership semantics?

Comment: You should take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196733/how-can-i-use-covariant-return-types-with-smart-pointers

Comment: I wonder about the claim that "The usual clone idiom makes use of covariant return types."  Personally I find it a hassle.

Comment: @John -- what about it is a hassle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's useful when you have a pointer to `Derived` and want to get a clone of it:

```
Derived *ptr = ...;
Derived *clone = ptr->clone();
```

without covariant return types you must do an explicit cast:

```
Derived *clone2 = (Derived*)ptr->clone();
```

Note that `Derived` may be a base class for even more derived classes, in that case it makes even more sense.

Unfortunately `auto_ptr<Derived>` and `auto_ptr<Base>` are not covariant. So you must return the same type from all clone functions in that case.

Comment: @ybungalobill: conclusion in last sentence incorrect, although it's true that the smart pointers are not covariant (per C++ rules). it's simple to emulate the covariance. e.g., see [my blog posting](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2010/06/12/cppx-3-ways-to-mix-in-a-generic-cloning-implementation/) on implementing reusable clone functionality in c++. cheers,

Comment: Summary of @Alf 's blog post - have a virtual function returning a pointer (overridden with covariant return type), and a public non-virtual function returning a smart pointer (overloaded in each derived class). That way, the caller always gets the smart pointer corresponding to the static type they called the function with. In Alf's example the virtual function is protected, although I don't immediately see why it isn't private.

Comment: @Steve: I agree that `private` would probably be better, however I am unsure as to returning a smart pointer from clone at all, mainly because it doesn't follow the `Clonable` concept from Boost.

Comment: @Alf: Yeah, I know. I use this technique myself.

Comment: @Matthieu: I think that's OK - if you want to implement `Clonable`, add a friend free function `new_clone` that calls the virtual function. Returning a smart pointer satisfies a style in which `auto_ptr` return values are used to "document" ownership of a new resource, and if the caller wants to use any other smart pointer type, they `release()` it. I prefer just to return the pointer and have the caller responsible for putting it into the smart pointer of their choice, and with C++0x that will *always* be `unique_ptr` rather than `auto_ptr` anyway, so the style in question should change.

Comment: @Steve: "document", as you mention, is very different from "enforce". A smart pointer enforces. Thus, you preference of returning a raw pointer is that you prefer to not enforce the ownership transfer. That doesn't make sense to me. The only freedom the caller gains is the freedom to mess up. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Alf: What I'm really curious about, is are you going to (a) leave all your interfaces as they are when you start using C++0x, with the deprecated `auto_ptr`; (b) switch them all to `unique_ptr`, possibly breaking compatibility a bit along the way; (c) use `unique_ptr` for new interfaces, rendering things inconsistent? I'm less bothered with the idiom if used with `unique_ptr`, since unlike `auto_ptr` it isn't stupid. The way I see it, your attempt to have people write code that correctly handles resources without thinking about it is noble but futile.

Comment: Mind you, at least with C++0x, you can probably write a perfect-forwarding template, so that instead of `new` you can use something that returns a smart pointer. Since in C++03, unacceptably(?), `new` doesn't enforce ownership transfer ;-p

Comment: @Steve: `auto_ptr` isn't going to go away, but it's a mess, yes. On the other hand, `auto_ptr` was always a mess (it's gone through, I don't know, three major revisions?), never working as per spec with Visual C++. I have no hard and fast advice on that, it depends... :-)

Comment: @Alf: well there you go, my strong preference isn't not to enforce ownership, it's not to enforce it *using `auto_ptr`*. Enforcing it using `shared_ptr` works, but forces your caller to use `shared_ptr` too, and not any other smart pointer of their preference. If it turns out that `unique_ptr` provides all of the advantages with none of the disadvantages, I'm open to reviewing my preference :-)

Comment: @Steve: well, an alternative for C++98 is to define your own little `Ownership` class, one that doesn't try to solve all the world's problems as `std::auto_ptr` does, but just the ownership issue. As it happens I've presented also an [`Ownership` class](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2010/05/23/cppx-ownership-with-custom-deleter/) at my blog, and is it happens, used in the last section of blog posting about `clone`. :-) He he. Cheers,

Answer (score 3):

> Since, presumably, I'm only accessing Derived objects through Base pointers and/or references when using this idiom...

You presume wrong. Just because a Base class exists doesn't mean you'll always be using it. If I have a `Shape` class with sub classes `Circle` and `Rectangle`, and I also have a `Window` class. I'm not going to use a `Shape*` for a the window's position and size when I can just use `Rectangle`.

For the transfer-of-ownership, you shouldn't be using smart pointers anyway. I know you don't want a lecture, but I'm not saying that smart pointers are bad, you just shouldn't be using them in `clone()`. You can't transfer ownership of something that has no ownership in the first place. If someone wants an `auto_ptr` then they should construct it with the cloned raw pointer. Same goes for other smart pointer types.

Comment: "when I can just use Rectangle" - so it's *your* fault all my windows have to be rectangular? Use `Shape*`!

Comment: Well in that case, I submit that you're already swimming in a sea of toxic design. Also, not sure your argument about "shouldn't be using [smart pointers] in `clone`" really holds water. It's as valid as any transfer-of-ownership scenario, is it not? The `clone` function creates (and thusly owns) the new object until it is returned to the caller.

Comment: @Tabber: there is no ideal smart pointer for the task, only `unique_ptr` has the required semantics, but this necessitates a C++0x compliant compiler (move semantics). `auto_ptr` is best unused whenever possible and other types of smart pointers introduce undue overhead.

Comment: @Tabber33: seriously? You think that a hierarchy of interfaces is "toxic design"? If so then why not complete that thought, and stop using dynamic polymorphism at all?

Comment: @Steve: of course not -- only insofar as OO is toxic design.  It sounded to me like, "I'll just use the derived class directly just because I happen to be able to, when I should really be using the proper interface class."  But I understand that occassionally one **needs** to access a derived class directly, and this is where the covariant return type is useful (to save the downcast after cloning).

Comment: @Tabber33: I think Peter's point was that windows genuinely are always rectangular, *by interface* not just by implementation. They have 4 corners, and a width and a height, and other things that aren't in the `Shape` interface. So the windowing system *must* use `Rectangle*`, or `IRectangle*` if you prefer to stress that it should be an interface. If it used the less specific `Shape` interface, it couldn't ask windows for their width and height, since not all shapes have those. Nevertheless, a `Rectangle` is a `Shape`, and hence has it as a base (presumably abstract) class.

Comment: So, I think you may be making an implicit assumption that "all base classes are interfaces and all derived classes are implementations", which is simply not true. One can have a hierarchy of interfaces (`Rectangle` extends `Shape`) and then have some concrete classes at the bottom of that (`ConcreteRectangle` and `TestLoggingRectangle` both extend `Rectangle`). `Rectangle::clone()` needs to return `Rectangle*`, or equivalent smart pointer, not merely `Shape*`.

Comment: @Steve: thanks, I've got all that.  I must admit I don't very often see well-designed code like you describe, where something as idiomatic as a clone function would be in use.  Perhaps my statement about _occassionally_ needing access to the derived class should have made more explicit the fact that I'm implying a simple design.  I think what tripped me up was Peter's wording: "I'm not going to use a `shape*`... when I can **just** use a `Rectangle*`" -- as though it's a matter of simplification to **just** use the derived class if it's accessible.  But anyway, I've got it now -- thanks!

Comment: @Tabber33: Ah, whereas I assumed that the existence of a `clone` function implies "enterprise" design, which even if effective isn't going to be simple, and probably involves a lot of interfaces...