# copy and swap idiom with pure virtual class

Tags: c++, class, virtual, copy-and-swap

I am trying to implement virtual class with pure virtual method and 'copy and swap' idiom, but I've encountered some problems. Code won't compile because I am creating instance in the assign operator of the class A which contains pure virtual method.

Is there a way how to use pure virtual method and copy and swap idiom?

```
class A
{
public:
    A( string name) :
            m_name(name) { m_type = ""; }
    A( const A & rec) :
            m_name(rec.m_name), m_type(rec.m_type) {}
    friend void swap(A & lhs, A & rhs)
    {
        std::swap(lhs.m_name, rhs.m_name);
        std::swap(lhs.m_type, rhs.m_type);
    }

    A & operator=( const A & rhs)
    {
        A tmp(rhs); 
        swap(*this, tmp);
        return *this;
    }

    friend ostream & operator<<( ostream & os,A & x)
    {
         x.print(os);
         return os;
    }

protected:
    virtual void print(ostream & os) =0;    

    string m_type;
    string m_name;
};

class B : A
{
public:
    B(string name, int att) :
        A(name),
        m_att(att)
        {
            m_type="B";
        }

    B( const B & rec) :
        A(rec),
        m_att(rec.m_att) {}

    friend void swap(B & lhs, B & rhs)
    {
        std::swap(lhs.m_att, rhs.m_att);
    }

    B & operator=( const B & rec)
    {
        B tmp(rec) ;
        swap(*this, tmp);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    virtual void print(ostream & os);

    int m_att;

};
```

Error message:

```
In member function ‘A& A::operator=(const A&)’:|
error: cannot declare variable ‘tmp’ to be of abstract type ‘A’|
because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘A’:|
virtual void A::print(std::ostream&)|
```

Comment: You can not have `A tmp(rhs);`. `A` is an abstract class.

Comment: @MohitJain I think he is well aware of that. That's why he is asking how to work around this.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14461532/1451714) is also helpful

Comment: The copy&swap idiom should not be combined with virtual functions/class hierarchies. That leads to slicing (and UB) and slow implementation (because your temporary copy object creates a full virtual function table). Instead, if you want duplication/assignment with a virtual base class, base your implementation on a [clone function with covariant return type](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4199613/186997).

Comment: BTW: The most advantages of copy-and-swap come if you do A & operator=( A rhs)
    {
        swap(*this, rhs);
        return *this;
    }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your compiler informs you, you cannot create a variable of abstract type. There is no way of dancing around that.

This leaves you three main options:

#### Stop using pure virtual functions

First, you could just get rid of the pure virtual methods and provide a little stub in each of them that calls [`std::terminate`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/terminate/), which would obviously break compile time detection of whether all (former) pure virtual methods are overridden in all derived classes.

This will cause [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c), since it will only copy the base class and everything that makes out the derived class is lost.

#### Use a stub class w/o pure virtual functions

Similar to that, you could create a derived class that implements all virtual methods with simple stubs (possibly calling [`std::terminate`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/terminate/)), and is used only used as a "instantiatable version of the base class".

The most important part to implement for this class would be a constructor that takes a const reference to the base class, so you can just use it instead of copying the base class. This example also adds a move constructor, because I am a performance fetishist.

This causes the same [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) problem as the first option. This may be your intended result, based on what you are doing.

```
struct InstantiatableA : public A {
    InstantiatableA(A const& rhs) : A(rhs) { }
    InstantiatableA(A&& rhs) : A(::std::move(rhs)) { }

    void print(ostream&) override { ::std::terminate(); }
};

A& A::operator=(InstantiatableA rhs) {
    using ::std::swap;
    swap(*this, rhs);
    return *this;
}
```

Note: This is really a variable of type `A`, although I said it could not be done. The only thing you have to be aware is that the variable of type `A` lives inside a variable of type `InstantiatableA`!

#### Use a copy factory

Finally, you can add a `virtual A* copy() = 0;` to the base class. Your derived class `B` will then have to implement it as `A* copy() override { return new B(*this); }`. The reason dynamic memory is necessary is because your derived types may require arbitrarily more memory than your base class.

Answer (score 1):

You're just facing the fact that inheritance works awkwardly with copy semantics.

For instance, imagine you found a trick to pass the compiling phase, what would mean (following example uses assignment but the issue is the same with a copy) :

```
// class A
// a class B : public A
// another class C : public A inheriting publicly from A
// another class D : public B inheriting publicly from B
B b1;
C c1;
D d1;

// Which semantic for following valid construction when copy/assignment is defined in A ?
b1 = c1;
b1 = d1;

A &ra = b1;
B b2;

// Which semantic for following valid construction when copy/assignment is defined in A ?
ra = b2;
ra = c1;
ra = d1;
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's question.

Comment: @lethal-guitar : Well, I think I do. This is because the question, to my mind, can't be answered correctly without creating a big design problem. So it answers the question by saying that the initial issue is in the wish to implement a copy and swap for an entity type.

Comment: I see, well you might consider editing this into your answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

CRTP is a choice:

```
template<typename swappable>
struct copy_swap_crtp{
    auto& operator=(copy_swap_crtp const& rhs){
         if (this==std::addressof(tmp))
            return *this;
         swappable tmp{rhs.self()};
         self().swap(tmp);
         return *this;
    };
    auto& operator=(copy_swap_crtp && rhs){
         self().swap(rhs.self());
         return *this;
    };
protected:
    auto& self(){return *static_cast<swappable*>(this);};
    //auto& self()const{return *static_cast<swappable const*>(this);};
};
```

user class:

```
struct copy_swap_class
: copy_swap_crtp<copy_swap_class>
{
    copy_swap_class(copy_swap_class const&);
    void swap(copy_swap_class&);
};
```

cheers,
FM.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler is right. The class `A` is abstract class, therefore you can not create instances of it in the `operator=`.

In B, you just declared the `print` function, but you didn't implement it. Meaning, you will get linking errors.

By implementing it, it compiles fine (if we ignore various warnings) :

```
void B::print(ostream & os )
{
  os << m_att;
}
```

by the way :

- B inherits privately from A, is that what you wanted?
- order of initialization in A's copy constructor is wrong
- you initialized m_type in A's constructor's body and not in the initialization list