# Virtual constructor with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism, smart-pointers

I am interested in whether it is possible to replicate the behaviour of the virtual constructor pattern (e.g. see [virtual constructor example](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-ctors.html)) using `std::shared_ptr`. The approach of replacing the raw pointers by shared pointers fails for obvious reasons (invalid covariant return type). I am interested if anyone knows of any alternatives that would support smart pointers.

Smart pointers are used everywhere in the project and the virtual constructor-like approach seems to be the only approach possible for the problem I am currently working on.

The code is provided below:

```
class A
{

public:

    virtual std::shared_ptr<A> clone(void) const = 0;

    virtual void mymethod() const = 0;

};


class B : public A
{

    std::shared_ptr<B> clone(void) const
        {
            return (new B(*this));
        }

    void mymethod() const
        {
            std::cout << "type something";
        }

};

class C
{


public:

    void mymethod(std::shared_ptr<A const> MyB)
        {
            std::shared_ptr<A const> MyB2 = MyB -> clone();
            MyB2 -> mymethod();
        }

};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return Type Covariance with Smart Pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924754/return-type-covariance-with-smart-pointers)

Comment: Why not return a `shared_ptr<A>` in all the classes? `shared_ptr`s use type-erasure internally, ensuring that information about the exact static type that was passed to the constructor is not lost, if that matters for your use-case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++'s covariant return type feature only supports raw pointers and references.

Supporting a single instance of clone function override is simple, but centralizing the boilerplate for multiple instances of clone function overriding is more problematic. Essentially this is the problem of expressing a covariant function implementation in a generic way, which C++ lacks direct support for. Possible solutions to that code generation include

- A macro.
  With C++03 this was the clear winner, but with C++11 and later it's only marginally (and possibly subjectively) the best.
- A middle-man inheritance mixin.
  This was technically possibly in C++03 but forwarding of constructor arguments became extremely much simpler in C++11.
- Dominance in virtual inheritance hierarchy.
  A complex technique that relies on a not well-known language feature somewhere.

Since the dominance solution is very complex and is only of academic interest, below I only exemplify (1) manual implementation of a single clone override, (2) defining a suitable macro, and (3) middle-man inheritance mixin.

---

Example of manual implementation of a single instance of clone function override:

```
// Manual implementation of a single clone function override.

#include <memory>

namespace my {
    using std::shared_ptr;

    class A
    {
    private:
        virtual auto virtual_clone() const
            -> A*
        { return new A( *this ); }

    public:
        auto clone() const
            -> shared_ptr<A>
        { return shared_ptr<A>( virtual_clone() ); }

        virtual void m() const {}
    };

    class B
        : public A
    {
    private:
        auto virtual_clone() const
            -> B* override
        { return new B( *this ); }

    public:
        auto clone() const
            -> shared_ptr<B> 
        { return shared_ptr<B>( virtual_clone() ); }
    };
}  // namespace my

void foo( std::shared_ptr<my::A const> b )
{
    std::shared_ptr<my::A const> b2 = b->clone();
    b2->m();
}

auto main()
    -> int
{ foo( std::shared_ptr<my::A>( new my::B ) ); }
```

---

Example of macro as a general solution:

```
// Macro-based centralization of covariant boilerplate code.

#include <memory>

#define MY_CLONE_IMPL( classname )          \
    private:                                \
        virtual auto virtual_clone() const  \
            -> classname*                   \
        { return new classname( *this ); }  \
    public:                                 \
        auto clone() const                  \
            -> std::shared_ptr<classname>   \
        { return std::shared_ptr<classname>( virtual_clone() ); }

void say( char const* );

namespace my {
    using std::shared_ptr;

    class A
    {
        MY_CLONE_IMPL( A )
    public:
        virtual void m() const { say( "A::m" ); }
    };

    class B
        : public A
    {
        MY_CLONE_IMPL( B )
    public:
        virtual void m() const { say( "B::m" ); }
    };
}  // namespace my

void foo( std::shared_ptr<my::A const> b )
{
    std::shared_ptr<my::A const> b2 = b->clone();
    b2->m();
}

#include <iostream>
void say( char const* s ) { std::cout << s << "\n"; }

auto main()
    -> int
{ foo( std::shared_ptr<my::A>( new my::B ) ); }
```

---

Example of a middle-man inheritance mixin as general solution:

```
// Middle-man mixin centralization of covariant boilerplate code.

#include <memory>       // std::shared_ptr
#include <utility>      // std::forward

struct Void {};

template< class Derived, class Base >
class With_cloning_of_
    : public Base
{
private:                              
    virtual auto virtual_clone() const
        -> Base*
    { return new Derived( static_cast<Derived const&>( *this ) ); }

public:                               
    auto clone() const                
        -> std::shared_ptr<Derived> 
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<Derived>(
            static_cast<Derived*>( virtual_clone() )
            );
    }

    template< class... Args >
    With_cloning_of_( Args&&... args )
        : Base( std::forward<Args>( args )... )
    {}
};

void say( char const* );

namespace my {
    using std::shared_ptr;

    class A
        : public With_cloning_of_<A, Void>
    {
    public:
        virtual void m() const { say( "A::m" ); }
    };

    class B
        : public With_cloning_of_<B, A>
    {
    public:
        virtual void m() const { say( "B::m" ); }
    };
}  // namespace my

void foo( std::shared_ptr<my::A const> b )
{
    std::shared_ptr<my::A const> b2 = b->clone();
    b2->m();
}

#include <iostream>
void say( char const* s ) { std::cout << s << "\n"; }

auto main()
    -> int
{ foo( std::shared_ptr<my::A>( new my::B ) ); }
```

---

If you want to use **`std::make_shared`** for the cloning then this complicates things a little.

One way to go about it, that doesn't introduce additional state like `shared_from_this` does, is to let the virtual cloning function return a `shared_ptr` to a known common ancestor.

One main problem with that is that introduces a degree of freedom, freedom to introduce bugs, but still that's just what one often does in C++, so I give this example:

```
// std::make_shared with middle-man mixin.

#include <memory>       // std::shared_ptr
#include <utility>      // std::forward

struct Void {};

template< class Derived, class Base, class Common_ancestor >
class With_cloning_of_
    : public Base
{
private:
    virtual auto virtual_clone() const
        -> std::shared_ptr<Common_ancestor>
    { return std::make_shared<Derived>( static_cast<Derived const&>( *this ) ); }

public:                               
    auto clone() const                
        -> std::shared_ptr<Derived> 
    { return std::static_pointer_cast<Derived>( virtual_clone() ); }

    template< class... Args >
    With_cloning_of_( Args&&... args )
        : Base( std::forward<Args>( args )... )
    {}
};

void say( char const* );

namespace my {
    using std::shared_ptr;

    class A
        : public With_cloning_of_<A, Void, Void>
    {
    public:
        virtual void m() const { say( "A::m" ); }
    };

    class B
        : public With_cloning_of_<B, A, Void>
    {
    public:
        virtual void m() const { say( "B::m" ); }
    };
}  // namespace my

void foo( std::shared_ptr<my::A const> b )
{
    std::shared_ptr<my::A const> b2 = b->clone();
    b2->m();
}

#include <iostream>
void say( char const* s ) { std::cout << s << "\n"; }

auto main()
    -> int
{ foo( std::shared_ptr<my::A>( new my::B ) ); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always fake covariant return types.

```
struct A {
  virtual shared_ptr<A> getA();
  shared_ptr<A> get() {
    return getA();
  }
};

struct B : A {
  virtual shared_ptr<B> getB();
  shared_ptr<B> get() {
    return getB();
  }
  shared_ptr<A> getA() {
    return getB();
  }
};
```

Comment: What's the point of the `virtual` in `virtual shared_ptr<B> getB();`?

Comment: @Cheers B may be not the last class in the hierarchy.

Comment: Are you envisioning a derived class C that gets virtual member functions `getA`, `getB` and `getC`, and so on? The number of virtual member implementations is then quadratic in the length of the inheritance chain. Also, I fail to see the *purpose* of it?

Comment: @Cheers Yes it is quadratic, but this is no different (implementation-wise) from straight covariant returns when the compiler has to apply pointer offsets (e.g. with multiple inheritance).

Comment: Well, a lot of debatable side issues here. But the question is, the *purpose*?

Comment: @Cheers Don't quite get the question. Obviously the purpose is to implement covariant return types without language support. Why this implementation? It doesn't use dynamic casts, for one.

Comment: Neither the `virtual` nor the public accessibility is needed to avoid casts. So what's the *purpose*? How do you envision this being used?

Comment: @Cheers I'm not sure what you are talking about. Covariant return types only make sense in context of virtual functions. Can you show me your implementation of `clone` function in a class hierarchy?

Comment: @Cheers Your solution wraps an existing plain-pointer covariant `clone*` implementation with a shared pointer, which I guess is OK when you have a plain-pointer function to wrap. I do not assume such function which makes it possible to use std::make_shared and such.

Comment: If you want to support `make_shared` you can use `shared_from_this` (and let the virtual function call the non-virtual one). There is about one pointers' worth cost in instance size. Or you can let the non-virtual function downcast a base smart pointer from virtual function. This would be at zero runtime cost. I didn't show or discuss that because I think it would be Microsoft-like over engineering.

Comment: @Cheers As for public access, nobody forces it. You can always separate virtual from public if that's your cup of tea. I didn't include access specifiers for simplicity.

Comment: Do you think I should add examples of these things?

Comment: @Cheers Yes, it will work. What if you are not implementing `clone` at all? What if you have a class hierarchy where each object has an associated object of the same type, which is fetched from a database or whatever, and plain pointers are not available?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf "Do you think I should add examples of these things" Yes, why not?

Comment: OK, will do. After all, to many C++ is all about taking some risks for efficiency's sake. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, C++ isn't really well-designed for this. one option is to do something like Peter Dimov's technique at http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2003/02/2996.php. In some applications, you can avoid this entirely by just having B's clone returns shared_ptr<A>. (I realize that is kind of cheating, which is why I began with Peter Dimov's more comprehensive solution, but sometimes it is best to avoid the problem entirely!)

Comment: –1 This is not an answer. It should possibly be a comment. Also the claim that C++ isn't well designed for this hangs free in the air as a subjective opinion (it's not obvious because solving the OP's direct problem, not done here, is trivial).