# Why isn't this combination of partially filled templates and interfaces allowed?

Tags: c++

I have a template class I'm trying to partially fill with functionality to provide a more high-level library. The template class has interfaces.

I'm running into an issue. When I try compile the following sample code demonstrating the problem, I get:

```
C2555   'concreter<int>::tuberMaker::makePotato': overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant from 'abstracter<int,U>::potatoMaker::makePotato'
```

However, this makes no sense as a tuber should be covariant with a potato - it explicitly inherits from potato! Why can't I use a tuber factory here? Is there a good workaround?

```
template <typename T,typename U>
class abstracter{
public:
    class potato
    {
    public:
        virtual void doSomething()=0;
    };
    class potatoMaker
    {
    public:
        virtual std::shared_ptr<potato> makePotato()=0;
    };
};

template <typename U>
class concreter
{
public:
    class tuber : public abstracter<int,U>::potato
    {
    public:
        void doSomething()
        {
            std::cout << "Something" << std::endl;
        }
    };
    class tuberMaker : public abstracter<int,U>::potatoMaker
    {
    public:
        std::shared_ptr<tuber> makePotato()
        {
            return std::make_shared<tuber>();
        }
    };
};

int main()
{
    concreter<int>::tuberMaker z = concreter<int>::tuberMaker();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Covariance only works for raw pointers and references. `std::shared_ptr` is neither.

Comment: I see- so the best course of action would be to return a tuber*?

Comment: @yuri kilochek nope, type erasure works with shared_ptr.. that's overloading virtual function is what doesn't work

Comment: @Swift `shared_ptr` uses type erasure to store the deleter, yes. I have no idea why you bring that up as that has nothing to do with the issue at hand. Overloading on return type indeed doesn't work, but you can override a virtual function with another one with a covariant return type, which is either a reference or a pointer to a subtype.

Comment: @yuri kilochek There is way to simulate  covariance  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924754/return-type-covariance-with-smart-pointers but fact that you can do that  doesn't mean that you should  do it. Same about using raw pointers for covariance, it's very peculiar case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because virtual methods can't return different type?  And why you need that, all that you need is a factory method that uses  type erasure.

```
    class tuberMaker : public abstracter<int,U>::potatoMaker
    {
    public:
        std::shared_ptr<typename abstracter<int,U>::potato> makePotato()
        {
            return std::make_shared<tuber>();
        }
    };
```

Assuming of course, that tuber is  descendant of potato (or child... or subclass... whatever you want to call it).  Using raw pointers that looks more understandable:

```
        potato* makePotato()
        {
            return new tuber();
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't seem you can do that - eg std::shared_ptr<abstracter<int,U>::potato> makePotato() just screams about the template argument.

Comment: @ProbablyAStupidQuestion in your case inheritance structure is  really fragged up.It actually doesn't recognize it as a type, you should use `typename` keyword:  `std::shared_ptr<typename abstracter<int,U>::potato> makePotato()`

Comment: That did it. This whole structure seemed like a really good idea at the time and now it no longer does...

Comment: @ProbablyAStupidQuestion maybe concreter must be child of abstracter, and you can use  `using` aliases. They will not work in this case, because it would be "different" type.. unless you'll make potato  a class in global namespace

Comment: Oh is that what that thing is for? I've seen it but not played with it.