# Official term for "overriding" a non-virtual method

Tags: c++, oop, naming

I'm using the "simulate covariance by casting" technique from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6925201). But I want to mark Derived::Clone with a comment that makes it clear that a method with the same signature and name exists in the base class as well. I had written:

```
/*shadow*/ shared_ptr<Derived> Clone() const
```

But I'm not sure the term "shadow" will be universally understood in this context. It seems to be more commonly used for local variables shadowing other local variables.

What's the official term for this kind of thing?

Comment: Shadowing seems perfectly fine, what's not understandable about it? The scope of a derived class is enclosed in its base class, and having an identical identifier in an inner scope is exactly shadowing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard (N4141) uses the term "hiding" for this, e.g.

> *Note:* The names declared in `V` and the left-hand instance of `W` are hidden by those in `B`, but the names
>   declared in the right-hand instance of `W` are not hidden at all. — *end note*

10.2/11

However, shadowing is a widely used term for all sorts of name hiding, so it is completely fine to use it in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

The term *shadowing* is widely used for doing such things related to scope.

Similar:

```
void foo(int x) {
   int x = 0; // << Shadows parameter x
}
```

Nothing *"official"* (I couldn't find the term used in the current standard draft document) but quite well understood IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I have came across two terms used to describe this kind of behaviour in a programming language - *hiding* and *shadowing*. I personally usually say that some function *hides* another function and that some variable *shadows* another variable.

btw. Wikipedia has an article called [Variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

I have also heard the term *name masking*, but not so often as *hiding* or *shadowing*.