# Inheritance on C++ Classes that contain another Derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, vector, dynamic-cast

Having the next C++ classes as a simplifiacation of the issue:

```
struct Car
{
    virtual int get_price() = 0;
};

struct ExpensiveCar: public Car
{
    int get_price( ) {/*..*/ }
    void apply_turbo( ){/*..*/};
};

struct CheapCar: public Car
{
    int get_price( ) {/*..*/}
};

struct CarRetailer
{
    virtual std::vector<Car*> get_cars( ) = 0;
};


struct ExpensiveCarsRetailer : public CarRetailer
{
    virtual std::vector<Car*> get_cars( ) { /*..*/ }
    std::vector<ExpensiveCar*> get_cars_for_exhibitions( );
};

struct CheapCarsRetailer : public CarRetailer
{
    virtual std::vector<Car*> get_cars( ) { /*..*/ }
    std::vector<CheapCar*> get_second_hand_cars( );
};
```

The rules are: Expensive Cars are only sold in ExpensiveCarsRetailers (similar for Cheap Cars ). Cheap cars do not have turbo and expensive cars are not sold in second hand.

The issue I face here is the coupling of classes that contains inherited classes as well. Therefore, if `ExpensiveCarRetailer` inherits from `CarRetailer`, it will need to implement 
`virtual std::vector<Car*> get_cars( )` that is actually returning a vector of `Car*`, however, internally `ExpensiveCarRetailer` only created objects of `ExpensiveCar`. Furthermore, the `get_cars_for_exhibitions()` is not included in the public interface `CarRetailer`therefore, it can return a `std::vector<ExpensiveCar*>` instead.

The mixture in the API ( returning vector of `Car*` and `ExpensiveCar*` ) is very ugly, and so is the code that the user needs to write to use the `apply_turbo( )` function of the list of cars from a specific `ExpesiveCarsRetailer`.

```
ExpensiveCarsRetailer ferrari;

std::vector<Car*> car = ferrari.get_cars();
ExpensiveCar* expensive_car;
for( int i = 0; i < car.size( ); ++i)
{
expensive_car = dynamic_cast<ExpensiveCar*>(car[i]);
expensive_car->apply_turbo();
}
```

I am sure I am missing some design pattern that helps in this situation, where to trees of class inheritances are coupled in a way that the abstract class of one of the inheritance tress need to return a vector (or set, list, etc ) of classes on the other inheritance tree. I am trying to avoid the dynamic casting as much as possible.

I also thought about making `CarRetailer` a templated class, therefore:

```
template<typename T>
    struct CarRetailer
    {
        virtual std::vector<T*> get_cars( ) = 0;
    };
```

And then make:

```
struct ExpensiveCarRetailer: public CarRetailer<ExpensiveCar>
{
...
}
```

But I don't think this would work since, for example, the `CarRetailer` can also start selling motorbikes ( similar structure as cars ) or bikes etc ( always applying the Expensive/Cheap pattern ) and eventually the number of template classes that need to be defined in `CarRetailer` will be huge.

Comment: Did you really mean to make all those members `private`? If not, replace `class` by `struct`.

Comment: Sorry, yes! Everything should be public. That is not the issue, I will try to change it

Comment: you should make this question in [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: My gut tells me that *expensive* should be a *property* of `CarRetailer`, not a descendant class.

Comment: @dlavila if it was made on Programmers, it would be closed as a [duplicate of this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/284033/how-do-i-override-the-type-of-members-in-a-base-class-from-the-derived-class)

Comment: @durron597 then he shouldn't have asked the question

Comment: @dlavila It's not off-topic here.

Comment: Relevant [link](http://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) from Programmers "duplicate"

Comment: @user3848107 Abstract Factory pattern is the perfect match for your example. Please check the UML diagram of this pattern and you will realize it.

Comment: @CreativeMind I dont think so. Abstract factory works if all inherited classes have the same interface. If applied in this case, you can use `ExpensiveCar` and `CheapCar` both as Car*. But if you want to use the specific function for `ExpensiveCar::apply_turbo` then you need to dynamic_cast the pointer coming from the factory.

Comment: @user3848107 You can create interface apply() only and pass the enum type that you want to apply and handle each type in switch case.

Comment: @RobertHarvey In fact, expensive should be property of car itself.

Comment: @CreativeMind: Yes, that's true.  Perhaps the property on CarRetailer is `Lavish`.

Comment: @CreativeMind, @RobertHarvey If expensive is a property of the car, the then the `Car` would implement both exclusive member functions `apply_turbo()` and `get_cars_in_second_hand()` . Being exclusive, the API is mixed with functions that belong to one specific type of `Car`. If tomorrow there is a new car `LuxuryCar` with an excluvie function `get_hollywood_stars_who_drove_it()`  This new function will in the end be again in the common interface `Car` since Luxury will also be a property of car, according to your approach.

Comment: The vector of `Car` pointers you get from `get_cars`. Are they owning raw pointers that the caller is responsible for deleting or just pointers to the cars that are owned by the retailer?

Comment: I put the example of raw pointers, but could also be shared_ptr or unique_ptr ( const ). The ownership of the generated vector of `Car` is of the caller. The messy API is what bothers me the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole concept of "coupling of classes that contains inherited classes as well" is called covariance. On Wikipedia one can find an extensive review of the subject: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science). But let's get back to the practical example: by writing

```
struct CarRetailer
{
    virtual std::vector<Car*> get_cars( ) = 0;
};
```

you are promising too much, i.e. that the `get_cars()` function will return a vector which you can modify with whatever `Car` you want. That is probably not what you meaned:

```
CarRetailer* ferrari = new ExpensiveCarsRetailer();
auto niceCars ferrari->get_cars();
niceCars.push_back(new Car{"Trabant"}); // you promised in the declaration that it was possible!
```

The solution is reducing the "promises" you do in the root class, returning a range which cannot be altered with "extraneous" objects. A read-only container would be nice, but alas, C++ is not (yet?) smart enough to support convariance on it:

```
struct CarRetailer
{
    virtual const std::vector<const Car*> get_cars( ) = 0;
};

struct ExpensiveCarsRetailer : public CarRetailer 
{
    const std::vector<const ExpensiveCar*> get_cars( ) = 0;
    // Alas, it won't override
};
```

But ranges (i.e. pointers pairs, in the hope that C++17 will offer something better) will do:

```
struct CarRetailer
{
    virtual Car* const cars_begin( ) = 0;
    virtual Car* const cars_end( ) = 0;
};

struct ExpensiveCarsRetailer : public CarRetailer 
{
    ExpensiveCar* const cars_begin( ) override {return cars->begin();}
    ExpensiveCar* const cars_end( ) override {return cars->end();}

    private:
    vector<ExpensiveCar>* cars; 
};
```

(note: I did not test my code, so please forgive possible mistakes. The concept should be clear, though)

This interface may seem uglier than the original one, but I am of the opposite opinion, since it integrates perfectly with the powerful `<algorithm>` C++ library and facilitates writing code in modern style. Here a simple example:

```
any_of(dealer.cars_begin( ), dealer.cars_end( ),
       [](const auto& car) -> bool {return car.hasScratch();}
) ? complain() : congratulate();
```

The biggest shortcoming of this design is that the `CarDealer` class has to own the `*cars` container and manage its existence, i.e. it must care that the pointers it returns stay alive. This is made difficult by the fact that one cannot return smart pointers, since C++ [does not support covariance on them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196733/how-can-i-use-covariant-return-types-with-smart-pointers). Additionally one could end up having to mantain a container of `vector<Car>*`, if the `cars_begin` and `cars_end` functions are supposed to generate new collections on repeated invocations. So it's up to you to balance pros and cons of my proposal in your concrete use case.

On a personal note, if I had the same issue I would use templated classes and avoid inheritance at all: such kind of problems IMHO well illustrates why OOP sometimes complicates things instead of simplifying them.

**EDIT**

If I understand well why you feel templated Dealers would not be indicated for your needs, I think this proposal should be more fit:

```
struct ExpensiveCarsRetailer /* not derived, not templated */
{
    std::vector<ExpensiveCar> get_cars( ) { /*..*/ }
    // you can also return a vector of pointers or of unique_pointers, as you feel like.
};

struct CheapCarsRetailer /* not derived, not templated */
{
    std::vector<CheapCar> get_cars( );
};
```

Instead of overloading, templated functions are used:

```
template <typename T> print_car_table(T dealer) {
    // This will work on both Expensive and Cheap dealers

    // Not even a hierarchy for the Car classes is needed:
    // they can be independent structs, like the Dealer ones

    auto cars = dealer.get_cars();

    for (const auto& car : cars) { std::cout << car.name() << "\t" << car.color() << "\n"; }
}

template <typename T> apply_turbo(T dealer) {
    // This will work if dealer is an ExpensiveDealer,
    // and fail on compile time if not, as wanted

    auto cars = dealer.get_cars();

    for (auto& car : cars) { car.apply_turbo(); }
}
```

The big advantage of this system is that you do not even have to plan the interface in advance, and each class can implement just the methods you need. So if in future you add a `CarMuseum`, you can decide to implement `get_cars()` to get `print_car_table(T)` work with it, but you are free not to create any other method. With inheritance, you are instad forced to implement all the functions declared in the base interface, or create many fragmented interfaces (`class CheapDealer : public HasACarList, public HasAPriceList, /* yuck ...*/`). .

The disadvantages of this templated design are the consequence of the Dealer classes not being relatives. This means you cannot create a `vector<Dealer>` nor have `Dealer*` (even if you made them derive from a tiny common interface, you could not call get_cars() through a pointer to such interface).

For completeness, I would point out the opposite, dynamic, solution:

```
struct Car {
    virtual int get_price() = 0;
    virtual void apply_turbo( ) = 0;
};

struct CheapCar: public Car
{
    int get_price( ) {/*..*/}
    void apply_turbo( ){throw OperationNonSupportedException();};
};
```

It does not feel very idiomatic C++, does it? I find it quite inelegant, but still I think this design should be evaluated before discarding it. Advantages and disadvantages are more or less the opposite of the templated solution.

Finally, I guess that the Visitor pattern or Scala (offering very powerful covariance facilities) could offer other alternative solutions to your problem. But I have no experience with both of them, so I leave them to others to illustrate.

Comment: Any hint on the shape of the templated classes in this example? I guess your approach will be different than the one I explained at the end of the main post ( including the reasons why I did not do it that way). So I am very curious :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a non-virtual function to get the cars just like you have done with `get_cars_for_exhibitions`? In the example you have shown the caller knows they have an `ExpensiveCarsRetailer` so they do not need the polymorphism. I assume you do need the inheritance and polymorphism in other contexts but it would be easy enough to convert from a vector of `ExpensiveCar` pointers to a vector of `Car` pointers to fulfil the `CarRetailer` interface:

```
template<typename T>
using Ptrs = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>;

template<class T, class U>
Ptrs<U> upcast(Ptrs<T> input) {
  return Ptrs<U>(std::make_move_iterator(input.begin()),  
                 std::make_move_iterator(input.end()));
}
struct CarRetailer {
  virtual Ptrs<Car> getCars() = 0;
};

struct ExpensiveCarsRetailer : CarRetailer {
  Ptrs<ExpensiveCar> getCarsImpl() { ... }
  Ptrs<Car> getCars() override { return upcast<Car>(getCarsImpl()); }
};
```

Then you can call the non-virtual function if you need a vector of `ExpensiveCar` pointers:

```
ExpensiveCarsRetailer ferrari;

auto expensive_cars = ferrari.getCarsImpl();
for (auto& expensive_car : expensive_cars)
  expensive_car->apply_turbo();
```

And in a polymorphic context you can call the virtual function:

```
CarRetailer* retailer = &ferrari;
auto cars = retailer->getCars();
for (auto& car : cars)
   std::cout << "Car price " << car->get_price() << "\n";
```