# Is it possible to make shared_ptr covariant?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, covariance

I tried to make the following example.

```
struct BaseSPtr{};
struct DerivedSPtr : public BaseSPtr{};


class Base{
    public:
    //virtual shared_ptr<BaseSPtr> function();
    virtual BaseSPtr* function();    
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
    //shared_ptr<DerivedSPtr> function() override;
    DerivedSPtr* function() override;
};
```

Can someone tell me if is it possible to make the example with `shared_ptr` valid?

Comment: If I understand the question, it is answered here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196733/

Comment: Here is [clear demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BNugYOEDlFLpemDt) what is the problem.

Comment: No, but a language variant supporting that would be ABI compatible.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no, covariance only applies to pointers and references in C++.

To have similar interface, you have to do something like :

```
class Base{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<BaseSPtr> function() { return std::shared_ptr<BaseSPtr>(function_v()); }
private:
    virtual BaseSPtr* function_v();
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<DerivedSPtr> function() // Hides Base::function
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<DerivedSPtr>(function_v());
    }
private:
    DerivedSPtr* function_v() override; // Overrides Base::function_v
};
```

CRTP might help to reduce duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Now question is how do you use `Derived` class?

- do you use it explicitly and polymorphic call `function()` is not performed?
- or do you keep this factory in some storage and `function()` is called in polymorphic way
- or do you use this in some templates

In first case just provide function with [different name](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7VIOUAGUJ74y7xo2), then you can invoke this function when pointer to derived class is needed.

In second case you should not try convince compiler that you return derived class since polymorphic call will hide this anyway.

In last case just use CRTP as other answer suggested (some call this static polymorphism) and drop virtual keyword.